# How to maintain aspect ratio while using weight in LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I have a vertical LinearLayout that contains two ImageView and two Buttons. ImageViews have a weight sum of 70, Buttons have a weight sum of 30. The two buttons have a specified aspect ratio and when Android resizes them with the specified weight, it changes only the height of the button by changing the aspect ratio.

Comment: I doubt that there is a solution for this with standard container classes. [I wrote an `AspectLockedFrameLayout`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts) that may be able to help, though I have not tried your specific scenario.

Comment: I solved my problem in the way described above. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using:

- ImageButton instead of Button
- android:src instead of android:background
- android:background="#00000000"
- android:scaleType="fitCenter"
- android:layout_width="match_parent"
- android:adjustViewBounds="true"